# Can we use React Native Firebase Push Notification on local (offline)

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

i just write a local push notification for android and ios use React Native Firebase. I wonder can i use RNFirebase Push Notification on local ( offline ). Can you guys have a solution for that?. Thank you!

Comment: react-native-firebase v6+ can't do that, maybe v5 can. You can use https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification or https://notifee.app/ Notifee is by the same people who made react native firebase, but it's in alpha & paid. I personally use react-native-push-notification

Comment: i got it. Thank you so much!